# How should application wide resources be organized?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, styles, resourcedictionary

Here is the scenario:

I have been using VS 2010 to write quite a large WPF project using MEF. There are multiple projects within this solution and I have one `ResourceDictionary` for all of my styles.

The `AppStyles.xaml` `ResourceDictionary` is located in my startup project, it contains all of my styles for the project. And within my `App.xaml` I have the following:

```
<Application x:Class="Dionysus.Shell.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         DispatcherUnhandledException="UnhandledException" ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <ResourceDictionary Source="AppStyles.xaml"/>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now, this all works perfectly in design mode of VS 2010 and when I am debugging, the correct styles are being applied to all of my controls. But I recently switched to VS 2012, and the designer is no longer working! When I debug it works perfectly but whenever I use one of my styles as follows:

```
<Button Name="btnForward" Height="23" Margin="10,0" Style="{StaticResource DionysusButton}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
```

I get the following error in the VS 2012 designer:

```
The resource "DionysusButton" could not be resolved.
```

I am clueless as to why this is happening, I have renamed my `Style`, and even the `ResourceDictionary` to no avail.

Is there a different way I should be doing this in VS 2012 or is this a problem with VS 2012?

I have found a lot of posts that say that changing the `x:Name` property of my `AppStyles.xaml` `ResourceDictionary` to `x:Key` will resolve this problem but I cannot do that as it is not a valid option for a `ResourceDictionary`.

Thanx in advance

-- UPDATE

I am using Marc's answer and all seems to be going well except for default styles. I have the following style:

```
 <Style TargetType="DataGrid" x:Name="DataGridStyle"/>
```

And this is my main `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Name="Main" 
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">


<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/AppStyling.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<Style TargetType="DataGrid" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}"/>
```

When I do not add the `Style` tag in my main `ResourceDictionary` it works fine, but the style is not being applied to all items obviously. When I do add it, i get the following exception:

> Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception

Ideas?

Comment: You mentioned `x:Name` but you don't say where that's relevant - it's not mentioned in any of your code.  You also don't say why you can't do that, which may be of use!

Comment: Sorry about that! I have updated my question.

Comment: No, idea. As far as I can see, everything looks fine. The exception is all-and-nothing. Is the DataGridStyle empty, or could something be wrong there? Try to remove the x:Name of the Main dictionary. You shouldn't need it anyway...

Comment: OKay I figured out the exception, it was caused by my style having the `x:Name` proeprty instead of `x:Key`. But styling is still not being applied to all of my `DataGrid` controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to use the styles which are located in your app.xaml in your modules which you export into the shell using PRISM? The modules should not have a reference to your application/shell project (the startup project)? Then they maybe just don't 'know' the project, which contains the styles? Though the question is why it works in VS2010 then... Please let me know, if I misunderstood your MEF scenario, I'll adapt my answer then.

Resources and Prism is abit tricky, and I am a fan of the following approach, which I have posted before, but it might help in your case too. It is much more appropriate for a PRISM solution than placing your resources inside app.xaml:

I usually create a seperate styling project, which I reference from the projects, which I want to style. The styling project has a fixed structure like this:

[image: Styling project]

For every control, I create a styling `ResourceDictionary`. For example for my buttons:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="PrimaryButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ToolbarButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In one main `ResourceDictionary`, I merge all the other dictionaries, in this case in the file IncaDesign.xaml, which you can see in the picture above:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Commons.Controls;assembly=Commons">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <ResourceDictionary Source="Converter/Converter.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Button.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="BitmapGraphics/Icons.xaml" />

    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <!-- Default Styles -->
    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource PrimaryButtonStyle}"></Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Notice how I defined the default styles, which are applied automatically, unless you specify otherwise. In every window or control, that you want to style, you only need to reference this one `ResourceDictionary`. Note the definition of the source, which is a reference to the assembly (`/Commons.Styling;component...`)

```xml
<UserControl.Resources>        
    <ResourceDictionary>            
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Commons.Styling;component/IncaDesign.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>  
        <!-- Here you can added resources which belong to the UserControl only -->
        <!-- For example: -->
        <DataTemplate x:Kex="UcTemplate" /> 
    </ResourceDictionary>        
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Default styles will be set automatically now, and if you want to access a resource explicitly, you can do this, using `StaticResource`.

```xml
<Viewbox Height="16" Width="16" Margin="0,0,10,0">
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource FileIcon32}" />
</Viewbox>
```

This is very nice solution in my opinion, which works for very complex solutions, including modular solutions, for example built with PRISM.

Comment: I like this solution a lot as it seperates the styles from any particular project, the only thing I am not too fond of is that I have to add `UserControl.Resources`  to every control, because as I mentioned this is quite a large application! Thanx a lot

Comment: Just a quick question, on a lot of my controls I already have a `<UserControl.Resources/>` element, so when I add my `ResourceDictionary` to it, it asks me to supply a `x:Key` for it, but when I do the styling does not work, what should I do in these cases?

Comment: Hi, I'm happy you like the solution. If your UserControls already have a ResourceDictionary, just add the three lines which add the reference to the MergedDictionary. I'll edit the answer, note the comment in the 3rd code listing.

Comment: I want to add, that you might run into trouble with this one. Usually it works fine, but if you have a lot of views, with this **one, big** dictionary referenced, performance issues might be the result. The bigger your dictionary gets, the slower instantiation of views is going to be, because the resource dict is instantiated for every view again! We got back to your first solution, even though design time mode was broken then.

Comment: The `ResourceDictionary` items can be broken up into multiple files, like it has been done above. One for buttons, one for converters etc. Would this not help the performance?

Comment: Check [this post](http://wpftutorial.net/MergedDictionaryPerformance.html) out for more information :) That's the important thing: *Each time a control references a ResourceDictionary XAML creates a new instance of it. So if you have a custom control library with 30 controls in it and each control references a common dictionary you create 30 identical resource dictionaries!*

Comment: I have not had any problems with this, but it definitely is a good point. Whether it becomes relevant or not probably depends on the structure of your GUI and its complexity, but it is a good point to look at. The problem with the SharedDictionary implementation is that you build yourself a memory leak. If you really run into performance issues, for now I would recommend to not use one big merged dictionary, but explicitly merge the dictionaries you actually need from the styling project. Organizing all resources in a separate project still makes sense imo...